# When I use css-position relative, how do I make it so that the elements original position does not block other floated elemnts position?

Tags: css

what the title says ;)

the place where the item used to be is now a void.

Comment: Can you please make an example on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `position: relative` is for moving elements without disturbing everying around. If you want to remove an element from the flow completely, use either `position: absolute` or `float: left/right`. If you want to move the element, but let other elements occupy the freed space, use negative margins.

You can even combine all three! For example, to have an element removed from the flow but positioned relatively to its original position, use `position:absolute` with no `top/left/right/bottom`, but move it with negative margins instead. Warning: inline and block elements will behave differently with that.

Comment: Awesome it was the part about negative margins i needed!